# Sharepoint 2013 - Error installing pre-requisite on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: 2013

I have been trying to get my Sharepoint 2013 installed on windows server 2012 R2. I was never able to get past the pre-requisite installer. It keeps failing at  "Configuring Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role" and was never able to get past that.

In the last 3 days i tried almost all of the suggestions posted in various forums but was never able to get it work. Any insight in to this error and resolution is greatly appreciated.

Tried all things explained here but didn't work

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2765260/en-us.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but, I have a vague memory about reading that you can not as of today install SP 2013 on Server 2012 R2. Something about it not being fully supported until SP1 of SP 2013.

Yes, found a source here about it being unsupported, listing your exact problem: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2013/09/22/sharepoint-2013-support-for-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx

So avoid 2012 R2 for SharePoint 2013 for now

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2012 R2 will be supported starting with SharePoint 2013 SP1 which currently has no release date.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your Server Manager .NET Framework 3.5 is probably not installed.

You have to manually install .NET Framework 3.5 (Server Manager Add Roles)

Install bits for .NET Framework 3.5 are not included as part of Windows 2012.

So at this point Pre Req installer and manual install method will try to locate the Windows Installer ISO for the .Net 3.5 install bits and it won't probably find it since you probably don't have the Windows 2012 Installer ISO still mounted.

The only way I knew was to install .NET Framework 3.5 manually and when prompted locate the source within the Windows 2012 installer ISO.

Hope that helps.

Comment: He is talking about 2012 R2 which is an unsupported platform for SP 2013 until SP1

Comment: I know he is talking about 2012 R2 but I don't think it will prevent the installation.

Comment: Maybe not, but Microsoft will not support your installation of SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found the answer on an article about SP 2010! - http://www.craiglussier.com/2012/03/01/install-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-server-8-beta/#Create_Emulated_ServerManagerCMD

Sharepoint is looking for a file that doesn't exist on Server 2012

Comment: SP1 is released now so you should really install SharePoint with SP1 streamlined install :)